# Find and Replace VBA with Nested Ifs

Tags: excel, vba, replace, nested

I'm trying to write a code that replaces text within a formula in a range of cells based on the value in a reference cell. I have the below worked out, but am still running an error. Any advice is much appreciated!

```
Sub FindRepRegion()
    If Active.Sheet.Range("J1") = "School" Then
        Dim Findtext As String
        Dim Replacetext As String
        Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$B:$B"
        Replacetext = "'Sheet1'!$AW:$AW"
        ActiveSheet.Range("E3:G35").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    ElseIf Active.Sheet.Range("J1") = "Grant" Then
        Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$AX:$AX"
        Replacetext = "'Sheet1'!$AW:$AW"
        ActiveSheet.Range("E3:G35").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    ElseIf Active.Sheet.Range("J1") = "Community School" Then
        Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$AY:$AY"
        Replacetext = "'Sheet1'!$AW:$AW"
        ActiveSheet.Range("E3:G35").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include in your question ([edit]) which error you get and in which line. Note that your `Dim` statement should be **before** your `If` statement otherwise the variables are not defined for the `ElseIf`s. • Also `Active.Sheet` should be `ActiveSheet`. • I recommend to activate `Option Explicit` to avoid such errors: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Thank you! That actually fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

@Pᴇʜ essentially answered your question, but here is the cleaned up code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindRepRegion()

    Dim Findtext As String
    Dim Replacetext As String

    Replacetext = "'Sheet1'!$AW:$AW"

    If ActiveSheet.Range("J1") = "School" Then
        Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$B:$B"
        ActiveSheet.Range("E3:G35").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("J1") = "Grant" Then
        Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$AX:$AX"
        ActiveSheet.Range("E3:G35").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("J1") = "Community School" Then
        Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$AY:$AY"
        ActiveSheet.Range("E3:G35").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    End If

End Sub
```

But since all your conditions are testing against the same range, might I suggest a `Select Case`? Also added a `With` statement.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindRepRegion()

    Dim Findtext As String
    Dim Replacetext As String

    Replacetext = "'Sheet1'!$AW:$AW"

    With ActiveSheet

        Select Case .Range("J1")
            Case "School"
                Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$B:$B"
            Case "Grant"
                Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$AX:$AX"
            Case "Community School"
                Findtext = "'Sheet1'!$AY:$AY"
        End Select

        .Range("E3:G35").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=Replacetext, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Why Option Explicit?

Comment: `Option Explicit` forces you to explicity `Dim` all your variables used in the subroutine/module. Essentially, it's a best practice and helps you debug large procedures with ease (like finding typos, etc.). You should always use it :)